# Слитно или раздельно пишется слово «не( )стеснённый»?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

«Не( )стеснённый материально» как пишется: слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: ***нестесненный материально.***

Пояснение

Существует глагол «***стеснить***»

**СТЕСНИТЬ**  4. кого-что. Лишить свободы действий, стать помехой для кого-, чего-л.; ограничить. Родители не хотели с. сына в выборе невесты. С. в проявлениях свободомыслия. С. в правах. Женитьба стеснила его свободу.

От глагола можно образовать **причастие** «не стесненный (чем-либо)», а также **прилагательное** "нестеснённый" (свободный) с переносным значением.

К причастию относятся **пояснительные слова в форме Т.п**., обозначающие инструмент действия (чем именно стесненный/не стесненный). При наличии **других пояснительных слов,** в том числе наречий, используется прилагательное «нестесненный» со слитным написанием НЕ.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

В конце концов манера его письма осталась при нем, и, **не стесненный никакими рамками** жанра, цензуры и прочих писательских условностей, он оставил в этих письмах необычайно интересную картину Англии…[Алексей Кузнецов. (2002)]

Поняв, что откопал золотую жилу, Алексей загнул цены так, что даже **нестесненного в средствах** продюсера из Надыма бросило в жар. [Ю. И. Андреева. Многоточие сборки (2009)] [омонимия не снята]